# How can the "vector of the unknowns" in matrix be a true vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How can the "vector of the unknowns" in matrix be a true vector?

In linear algebra,if
$$\begin{cases}
x-3y=-1 \\
x+y=2\end{cases}$$
then the system can be written as $Av=b$, where $A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & -3\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ , $v = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$b = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

And this $v$ is called the vector of the unknowns.

But a vector should have length and a size, right? So how can this be a true "vector"? $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ does not have a set length or a size; rather, it is inherently undefined, or incomplete, in my opinion. (It is not possible to draw $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$).

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ in the original equations “true” numbers in your mind?

Comment: You can think of $v$ as an "unknown vector" just as in high school algebra, when $x$ is an "unknown number" you want to find by solving an equation.

Comment: Variables [b]are[/b] numbers and variable vectors [b]are[/b] vectors!  The vector (x, y).  Your statement "a vector should have length and a size" is correct.  But in the very next sentence, you change to "a **set** length or a size" (emphasis mine).  That is not correct.

Comment: If you have found your answer, please consider closing the question by selecting an answer for the question.

Comment: I still don't feel convinced after reading answers so far, though I appreciate your feedback. here's my thought to all of you-- I think an accurate description is: "an unknown vector in the x, y space," instead of  "vector of unknowns."

Comment: In reply to Ethan above, think about this. If x=n, where n is an integer, what is the accurate description of "x"? Is that an "integer of unknown," or is it an unknown integer? Just from "x=n, where n is an integer," it is not implied clearly whether this x is specifically referring to one value, or is a COLLECTION of all values that satisfy the description. x, in other words, may be more of an infinite series, not an integer. Similarly I find that (x;y) should be defined as an unknown vector of x-y space, NOT as a vector of unknowns.

Comment: For what it's worth, "$x=n$, where $n$ is an integer" is precisely synonymous with "$x$ is an integer". I think you have a nonstandard interpretation of the concept of a variable.

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question in this page, please upvote the answer to close the question.

Comment: Rahul you missunderstand the point. Yes I don't deny x is an integer. but is it accurate to say "x is an integer of UNKNOWN?" what does that even mean? Doesn't that sound more like a series, where you talk about all possible x values that  satisfy x=n, n is an integer? Likewise, describing x=(x;y) is a "vector of unknowns" is ambiguous.

Comment: (Tip: If you write "@Username" instead of just "Username" in your comment it notifies the person that you have replied. Others aren't doing that to you in their comments because you are automatically notified of comments on your own posts.)

Comment: It makes no sense to say "$x$ is an integer of unknown", just like you don't say "$5$ is an integer of known". However, one does say "$\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}$ is a vector of integers" meaning it is a vector whose entries are integers, and similarly one can say "$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ is a vector of unknowns" meaning it is a vector whose entries are unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  It's a very specific quantity.

... And, like every other expression containing variables, has a definite value when you bind values to the variables.  (And the resulting length is the same as the length of the likewise bound vector.)

---

In comments, the OP asks a follow-on quetsion about the direction of the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.  Elaborating on the implicit solution...

From $\sin \theta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, we get $\theta = \sin^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + 2 \pi k$ or $\theta = \pi - \sin^{-1} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + 2\pi k$ for any integer $k$.  This gives two infinite families of solutions, $U$.  From $\cos \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, we get $\theta = \pm \cos^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + 2\pi k$, for any integer $k$.  This gives the two infinite families of solutions, $V$.  Then the infinite family of solutions $U \cap V = \theta + 2\pi k$, for any integer $k$, gives every angle coterminal with the direction of the vector.

Comment: what is, then, in the similar manner, the "direction" of the said vector? Is it possible to express in mathematical terms the direction of the general (x; y) vector?

Comment: @SK : Depending on what you consider elementary functions, the direction of the vector is [`atan2(y,x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). Equivalently, it is any of the solutions in $\theta$ to the system $\left\{ \sin \theta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \cos \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The vector of unknowns is not "undefined." The length of the vector is equal to the number of unknowns in the systems of equations. In other words, if A is $m x n$, then $v$ is of dimension $nx1$. The only things that are "incomplete" are the entries of the vector. (But those can be found via multiple methods e.g. elimination, inversion, etc).

Remember that for matrix multiplication to work the columns of the first matrix should equal the rows of the second. In other words, for matrices $A$, $B$ with dimensions $mxn$ and $cxd$ respectively, the matrix multiplication $A*B$ is defined if and only if $n = c$. (The resulting matrix would be of dimension $mxd$).

**EDIT**: Direction of a vector: There is no "formula" or a "mathematical" way to express the direction of a vector besides giving the vector's unit vector. Consider the following example: $$v =\begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 8\\\end{bmatrix}$$The length of $v$ would be:$$\sqrt{6^2 + 8^2} = 10$$To find the unit vector of $v$, you would simply divide each entry of $v$ by $10$: $$v_u = \frac {1}{10}* \begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 8\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.6 \\ 0.8\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This seems to be in conflict with the explanation by Eric above, who said the length is route of (x^2+y^2). Don't know which is correct. Question to you then--if  n is the length of v, then what is the direction of v?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My wording was incorrect. I meant the dimension was n by 1. Eric is correct regarding the length.

Comment: As per your question regarding direction of a vector: The direction of a vector is what it sounds like (direction of vector is the direction in which it is pointing). There is no mathematical term per say to express direction. Typically instead we turn the vector into an unit vector and say that unit vector is the direction of the vector.

Comment: Just to be clear, the when we say length of a vector, we are referring to the geometric length (ie the length when you draw the vector). The number of components in a vector is NOT the length, it is the dimension.

Comment: Yes, good to distinguish length vs dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I came to my own conclusion that perhaps the correct answer to my question is that vector is not defined as an entity with a length and a width. Rather, it is defined as an element of a vector space that satisfies the ten vector space axioms. If I understood that was how a vector is defined, then it would have made so much more sense that one does not have to worry about an undetermined length and direction. Ex, doesn’t make sense to say, is v=sinx a vector? What is the direction or length of the vector? But make sense v=sinx is a vector as it fits as an element within a vector space.

Comment: Things with magnitude and direction are vectors. But not all vectors are things with magitude and direction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about the problem is in term of linear transformations (transformation that keep the origin fixed, and keep parallel lines parallel). Matrices are a convenient way of packaging the information necessary to describe a particular linear transformation -- the first column describes the location that the unit vector in the one direction is sent, and the second column describes where the unit vector in the orthogonal direction is sent; this information is enough to uniquely describe the transformation. So when you look at an equation of the form: $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} $$ you should read it as asking the question "considering that the linear transformation sends the vector [1,0] to [a,c] and [0,1], what vector [x,y] under the same transformation, will be sent to [u,v]." That way, it's easy to imagine the vector [x,y] as a "roaming" vector, searching for the right length and direction so that the linear transformation will send it to [u,v]. Watch 3blue1browns videos on linear algebra for excellent visualizations of this idea.